# How to make this neighbor function?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have this code:

```
(defparameter fc #\F)
(defparameter bc #\B)
(defparameter gap #\G)

(defun solp (seq)
    (if (eql fc (car seq))
        (not (if (listp (cdr seq))
                 (find bc (cdr seq))
                 (eql seq bc)))
        (solp (cdr seq))))

(defun heuristic (seq &optional (f 0)) 
    (if (eql nil seq) 
        0   
        (if (eql bc (car seq))
            (+ f (heuristic (cdr seq) f)) 
            (heuristic (cdr seq) (+ f 1)))))

(defun genneighbors (seq)

    ;seq == (fc fc gap bc bc) ===> neighbors == ( (gap fc fc bc bc)
    ;                                              (fc gap fc bc bc)
    ;                                               (fc fc bc gap)
    ;                                               (fc fc bc bc gap) )
    ;I can't figure out how to do this
)
```

I can't figure out how to code the `genneighbors` function. How do I access an element (2 | 1) slots before `gap` How to generate all four possible neighbors? Can someone give me some pointers?

Comment: Is this homework? From the code and the example, it is hard to infer what the functions should do, what input they should accept and what output they should generate. 'heuristic' for example is a generic name. More interesting would be what kind of heuristic it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the functions from the CLHS chapters [conses](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_conses.htm) and [sequences](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_sequen.htm) apply to lists.

Also note that it is good programming style (for various reasons) to name global variables like this: *bc*, *fc* and *gap*.

Also note that in newer code one often uses FIRST instead of CAR and REST instead of CDR.